# Connect AWS database to files in VScode

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, amazon-rds, vscode-extensions

I have already made front end pages using html css and js and I wanted to use the aws rds mysql database in it. The db is connected to the databse in vs code but how do I access it in the php file?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With your short explanation and screenshot's what I have understood is that you are developing an app with a front end (html, css, js) and you want to connect this app to a database through the php file.

So in order to connect and access your database in the php file you need to download the php client for Mysql, the name is [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and you can find many videos in YouTube. The purpose of this library is to talk to your database, is the only reasonable way to do it.

Second you need to get the credentials from the rds service. So far you have expressed that you where able to connect visual studio to the db, so you already have the credentials.

When you start to see the basic tutorials on how to use mysqli everything will come to sense

Good luck!